# What are the use cases for class based generic views for django

Tags: django, oop, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to write some generic boiler plate code for creating facebook apps.  I am writing a separate FacebookUser class  instead of django's standrd contrib.user app. I am wondering if it would be a good design decision to actually write all oauth steps using class based generic views . What is the point of using class based genric views and why and where should i use them

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370650/what-is-the-advantage-of-class-based-views

Answer (score 0):

Any Repetitve process that would benefit from an object oriented approach.  For me I create a lot of utilities that allows users to download data as a CSV,  I have implemented a `CSVResponseView` view that returns a csv with the correct content types.  This makes it easier for me to test, and lends itself to a more consistent easier to maintain implementation then function based views.